# AngularJS Directive detect passed in model property change

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive with an isolated scope. I want to detect changes of an attribute that is a variable on the parent scope.

I have the following so far:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("called");

    $scope.isReady = true;
    $scope.$apply();
  }, 2000);


});

app.directive("car", function($log) {
  return {
    scope: {
      make: "=carMake"
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<strong ng-bind='make'></strong>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.$watch(attrs.shouldDo, function(value) {
        var val = value || null;
        if (val) {
          $log.info(scope.$eval(attrs.shouldDo));
        }
      }, true);

    }
  }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8Qhuk/

If I set scope as `false` it works, However I need it to work with an isolated scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write `scope` part as:

```
 scope: {
        make : "=carMake",
        shouldDo: '='
    },
```

Fixed Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8Qhuk/6/)**</kbd>

The directive example:

```
app.directive("car", function($log) {
    return {
        scope: {
            make: "=carMake",
            shouldDo: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<strong ng-bind='make'></strong>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {    

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.shouldDo
            },
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var val = newValue || null;
                if (val) {
                    $log.info(scope.shouldDo);
                }
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

In `watch` we listen for one varaible only. You don't need `true` flag

---

BTW, you can use *bind once* for read-only

```
 scope: {
        make : "=carMake",
        shouldDo: '@'
    },
```

when HTML:

```
<car car-make="make" should-do="{{isReady}}"></car>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8Qhuk/8/)**</kbd>